# Implementing token bucket algorithm

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I'm currently working on implementing a token bucket algorithm in JavaScript to monitor the number of requests per second. The objective is to allow requests to proceed if there are sufficient tokens available in the bucket, otherwise, the system should enforce rate limiting.
However, upon testing my code, I observed that it consistently outputs 'false'. Should I incorporate the use of setInterval to ensure its proper functionality?

```js
 class TokenBucket {
        constructor(maxBucketSize, numberOfRequests, windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliseconds) {
            this.maxBucketSize = maxBucketSize;
            this.numberOfRequests = numberOfRequests;
            this.windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliseconds = windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliseconds;
            this.refill();
        }
    
        tryConsume() {
            this.refill();
            if (this.numberOfTokenAvailable > 0) {
                this.numberOfTokenAvailable--;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    
        refill() {
            if (Date.now() < this.nextRefillTime) {
                return;
            }
            this.lastRefillTime = Date.now();
            this.nextRefillTime = this.lastRefillTime + this.windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliseconds;
            this.numberOfTokenAvailable = Math.min(this.maxBucketSize, this.numberOfTokenAvailable + this.numberOfRequests);
        }
    }
    
    // Example usage:
    const tokenBucket = new TokenBucket(10, 5, 10000); // Max bucket size: 10, 5 requests per 10 seconds
    console.log(tokenBucket.tryConsume()); // Outputs: true (tokens available)
    console.log(tokenBucket.tryConsume()); // Outputs: true (tokens available)
    console.log(tokenBucket.tryConsume()); // Outputs: true (tokens available)
    console.log(tokenBucket.tryConsume()); // Outputs: true (tokens available)
    console.log(tokenBucket.tryConsume()); // Outputs: true (tokens available)
    console.log(tokenBucket.tryConsume()); // Outputs: false (no tokens available)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: This isn't how the token bucket algorithm is supposed to work.  There should be no window size.  Tokens are added one at a time at a steady rate, not all at once.

Comment: @MattTimmermans could you provide an answer with that thanks

Comment: Sure, if this question is still open by the time I get around to it.  I've been waiting for an excuse to talk about token bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to init

```
this.nextRefillTime = -Infinity;
this.numberOfTokenAvailable = 0;
```

```js
 class TokenBucket {
        constructor(maxBucketSize, numberOfRequests, windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliseconds) {
            this.maxBucketSize = maxBucketSize;
            this.numberOfRequests = numberOfRequests;
            this.windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliseconds = windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliseconds;
            this.nextRefillTime = -Infinity;
            this.numberOfTokenAvailable = 0;
            this.refill();
        }
    
        tryConsume() {
            this.refill();
            if (this.numberOfTokenAvailable > 0) {
                this.numberOfTokenAvailable--;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    
        refill() {
            if (Date.now() < this.nextRefillTime) {
                return;
            }
            debugger;
            this.lastRefillTime = Date.now();
            this.nextRefillTime = this.lastRefillTime + this.windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliseconds;
            this.numberOfTokenAvailable = Math.min(this.maxBucketSize, this.numberOfTokenAvailable + this.numberOfRequests);
        }
    }
    
    // Example usage:
    const tokenBucket = new TokenBucket(10, 5, 10000); // Max bucket size: 10, 5 requests per 10 seconds
    console.log(tokenBucket.tryConsume()); // Outputs: true (tokens available)
    console.log(tokenBucket.tryConsume()); // Outputs: true (tokens available)
    console.log(tokenBucket.tryConsume()); // Outputs: true (tokens available)
    console.log(tokenBucket.tryConsume()); // Outputs: true (tokens available)
    console.log(tokenBucket.tryConsume()); // Outputs: true (tokens available)
    console.log(tokenBucket.tryConsume()); // Outputs: false (no tokens available)
```

Comment: Should i use setInterval ? I just wanted to know best:correct way to implement it

Comment: @art i think setInterval or setTimeout is not optimal. imagine you could have the server without requests (waste of CPU on triggering intervals) + setInterval/setTimeout aren't precise, no warranty they are executed at an exact needed moment. time offsets like you use are better imho

Comment: but isn't in the Tokenbucket algorithm tokens are added one at a time at a steady rate, not all at once?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code lies in the refill() method. It doesn't correctly refill the token bucket based on the time elapsed since the last refill.

```js
refill() {
    if (Date.now() < this.nextRefillTime) {
        return;
    }
    this.lastRefillTime = Date.now();
    this.nextRefillTime = this.lastRefillTime + this.windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliseconds;
    this.numberOfTokenAvailable = Math.min(this.maxBucketSize, this.numberOfTokenAvailable + this.numberOfRequests);
}
```

The refill() method checks if the current time is past the next refill time.
If it's time to refill, it updates the lastRefillTime, calculates the next refill time, and refills the bucket by adding numberOfRequests tokens.

Corrected Implementation:

```js
refill() {
    const currentTime = Date.now();
    const timeElapsed = currentTime - this.lastRefillTime;
    const tokensToAdd = Math.floor(timeElapsed / this.windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliseconds) * this.numberOfRequests;
    
    if (tokensToAdd > 0) {
        this.lastRefillTime = currentTime;
        this.numberOfTokenAvailable = Math.min(this.maxBucketSize, this.numberOfTokenAvailable + tokensToAdd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Token bucket is a great rate limiting algorithm, but it doesn't work the way you're trying to write it.  The way to *think* about token bucket is:

- Each allowed request takes a token out of the bucket. If a request comes in when there are no tokens, the request is denied.
- Tokens get added to the bucket one at a time, at a steady rate, as long as the number of tokens in the bucket is less than the burst limit.

The rate limit and burst limit are parameters of the algorithm.

This algorithm has a lot of advantages.  It corresponds closely to the capabilities of the systems it protects, which makes it very useful.  It also doesn't have any strange behavior associated with arbitrarily chosen "time windows" like more naive rate limiting algorithms do.

It's also **super easy to implement**.  If you do it right, it requires only one word of state, which you can update atomically, and you only need to update that state when you *allow* a request -- no timer events of any kind are required.

The way you should implement token bucket, though, is different from the way you think of it...

At any point in time, the bucket has some number of tokens in it.  Left alone, the bucket will fill up until it reaches the burst limit.  Let's call the time when it reaches that limit the *fill time*.

Imagine that, instead of keeping track of the current number of tokens in the bucket, we just keep track of the corresponding fill time.  This allows us to deduce, at any time in the future, how many tokens are in the bucket:

- If `current_time > fill_time`, then `tokens = burst_limit`.  Easy.
- If `current_time < fill_time`, then `tokens = burst_limit - rate_limit * (fill_time-current_time)`.  Also easy.  If this is less than 1, then you should deny the request.

The great thing about using the fill time is that it only changes when you allow a request.  That's why you don't need any timer events or anything like that.  This gets you most of the way to a good token bucket implementation.  But there are a couple of further optimizations that I like to make.

1. Let `t1_time = fill_time - (burst_limit-1) / rate_limit`.  This is time in the past when a one-token bucket would fill to the current capacity.  I like to keep track of this instead of fill time, because you can directly compare it the the current time, and allow a request when `t1_time <= current_time`.
2. Instead of keeping track of time in seconds or milliseconds, keep track of time in *tokens*.  That is `token_time = clock_time * rate_limit`.  This change means that the state (`t1_time`) that you track can always be an integer, solving a lot of tricky problems around rounding, etc.

With all that, a token bucket implementation is super easy, as promised:

```javascript
class TokenBucket {

    constructor(ratePerSecond, burstLimit) {
        // Factor that converts time in milliseconds to time in tokens
        // This isn't necessarily an integer
        this.tokensPerMilli = ratePerSecond*1000;
        // The difference, in token time, between the one-token-in-bucket time
        // and now, if we just took a token from a *full* bucket
        this.fullBucketLag = burstLimit-2;
        // Now, in tokens instead of milliseconds
        const tokenNow = Date.now() * this.tokensPerMilli;
        // Initialize the one-token-in-bucket time so that the bucket is
        // initially full.  In another language, you could use an integer
        // data type for this.
        this.t1Time = tokenNow-burstLimit;
    }

    tryConsume() {
        // Now, in tokens instead of milliseconds
        const tokenNow = Date.now() * this.tokensPerMilli;
        if (tokenNow < this.t1Time) {
            // denied
            return false;
        } else {
            // allowed
            this.t1Time = Math.max(this.t1Time + 1, tokenNow - this.fullBucketLag);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Explanation Matt Timmermans